# Windows Server Docker Containers High I/O

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, windows-server-2019

I am having some trouble with some unusual high rates/spikes(very long period of time) of I/O in regards to the disk, when using Docker containers on windows server 2019 . Is there a way to limit or maybe to investigate further what can be the cause to this sort of manifestation? I have found some solutions but all of them were applicable on linux. Unfortunately I am running containers on windows server.

Comment: What is your docker desktop version ?

Comment: Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88

Comment: Maybe you can try earlier version, like [2.5.0.1](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/)

Comment: is there a way or a command that could output info about a specific container with detailed info? aside docker stats ?

Comment: Do you mean `docker inspect container_name` ?

Comment: not sure, I would have liked to know if there is a way. cause I have a SQL container and I think it's creating so many w/r that's it's slowing down the entire machines on that disk

Comment: I'm using docker on linux machine, sorry for not able to  provide helpful information.